# Getting email address of a user who filled columns of SharePoint list

Tags: list, email, json-formatting

I have a SharePoint list with 100 users and they are invited to do the following:

The first column has the users's name. The users have to find their name and answer the questions on column 2,3 and 4.

When they finish answering, I want their email address to automatically appear on column 5. I also want to prohibit the users from manually changing the values on column 5.

Since I don't have an access to Power Automate, can someone suggest me how to do it using JSON?

Comment: If only one user is modifying the list item/entry, you can use SharePoint default **Modified By** column which stores the name of user who modified the list item.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, That's a great idea, but I have a few problems. Because I entered the information of the first column, all of them are shown to be modified by me until they actually make an adjustment. Also I can't change my column name from"Modified By" to something else. Could you suggest a solution please?

Comment: Modified by column is SharePoint default column & you cannot modify it. Also, it stores the name of person who modified the list "item" last time (latest modification).

Comment: @GaneshSanap I understand. Could you think of alternative way of solving problem except for using Modified Column?

Comment: No SharePoint out of the box way available. You have to customize the list form using Power apps in case of SP online.